# Cannot find php_sqlsrv extension - 5.3, threadsafe

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've followed the answer to this question to the letter:

[Connection between MSSQL and PHP 5.3.5 on IIS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425322/connection-between-mssql-and-php-5-3-5-on-iis-is-not-working)

I'm using XAMPP with threadsafe 5.3. I've copied the files to the extension directory (while leaving them in the /php folder) and I've added the extension lines:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

When I do this, Apache fails to start, giving me errors in `eventvwr` like:

```
Application popup: Warning : PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll' 
- The specified module could not be found.
```

Except, obviously, that that file DOES exist in that spot, and php.ini is pointed at that extension directory.

What's the problem?

Comment: unable to load also means unable to access. make sure that whatever UID php is running under has access rights on the file.

Comment: Just checked. The relevant files have the same permissions as the other extensions in the directory.

Comment: Was the library compiled using the same compiler? If you check phpinfo(); you should be able to see the compiler used for PHP.

Comment: I just downloaded the libraries from Microsoft. How would that make a difference? I can't compile them differently, right?

Comment: Not that this helps necessarily, but i have the exact same problem with a different .dll:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693859/winxp-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-ibm-db2-dll

Comment: If you take out the two extension= lines, does apache then restart correctly?

Comment: Yes - it restarts fine if I comment out the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, none of the answers addressed the issue or were avenues I had already explored.

I have decided to use the ODBC drivers with a SQL Server connection string, which seems to work fine, minus the fact I can't use MSSQL and SQLSRV native functions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows reports this when a shared lib dependency *of what you're loading* is missing.  Use depends.exe to view the dependencies of php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll and make sure it's either previously loaded or in the shared library search path.

http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: FYI:: I ran this against my ext/php_ibm_db2 <which works on our server> and it came up with about 50 dependencies.  Almost none of those dependencies are in the /ext folder.  This makes me wonder how accurate the tool is, or if i'm not understanding its use correctly.

Comment: This didn't seem to help (crashed actually when I ran it against the relevant files), but thanks for answering. (#mtgpro4L, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

See below url

[php_sqlsrv.dll: gives error when checking PHP version but extension works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422452/php-sqlsrv-dll-gives-error-when-checking-php-version-but-extension-works)

Read it:-

Since PHP 5.3, Microsoft has a new driver for windows :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Maybe you can try this version, which seems quite recent (06/2011)

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

I have written a page that might help when installing the SQLSRV driver:
http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html

Unfortunately the instructions got complicated when MSFT removed the download for the old XP/2003 driver (version 2.0), so read the whole page before starting.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your answer if I ever need it. I switched to a Linux/FreeTDS setup.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong technology, but I was having problems getting WAMP to connect to MSSQL, with the same types of errors.

I fixed the problem by installing the 32-bit version of WAMP (instead of 64, even though we were on a 64-bit system).

Even if that's not applicable to the OP, I hope someone finds this helpful!

Comment: It's not helpful for this question, but thanks for adding it!

Comment: @Kyle - just a heads up to make sure all of your stuff (esp. xampp) is 32-bit since that caused the error for us. Best of luck in finding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error messages when I started the Drupal 7 stack after installation. I am  using VM Ware with Win 7 x64 and acquia-drupal-win-7.31.36-6159.54300.

I went to the PHP site  http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php  and installed the x64 Package.
steps
1) Stop Drupal Stack
2) run the file:  sqlncli.msi
3) restart Drupal, and no error messages.